# The fastest and most scalable way to write a nested loop

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, conditional, procedural-programming, infinite-loop

The problem is to find the weights `{w1,w2,w3,w4}` that satisfy the condition. Which is the fastest and most scalable way (e.g. for 10000 weights) to write this conditional nested loop without using parallelization?

```
Do[If[a^2 + b^2 == w1 a ^2 + w2 a b^2 + w3 a^3 + w4 b^2,
  Print[w1, w2, w3, w4]],
 {w1, -1, 1}, {w2, -1, 1}, {w3, -1, 1}, {w4, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: Generally, the fastest solution to a heavily nested and iterated problem is to rephrase it to not require nesting and iteration. Do these weights need to be integers or have some other quality other than satisfying the equality?

Comment: Maybe something like Reduce[a^2 + b^2 == w1 a^2 + w2 a b^2 + w3 a^3 + w4 b^2, {w1, w2, w3, w4}]

Comment: Also note that you don't really want to `Print` in mathematica—that's just for user display. To actually *get* the weights, you'll want to e.g. put them in a list and have this expression evaluate to that list—something that actually gives you data that can be stored

Comment: also to be clear are `a` and `b` constants here? And are the possible values of each weight exactly `-1`, `0`, and `1`?

Comment: Sorry, for not explaining clearly. The possible values of each weight are integers exactly -1, 0, and 1. The `a` and `b` are symbolic variables that we don't mind what they are. Just we search for the weights that satisfy the equality. I would be grateful if someone can give the above code using `Table` that I heard that is faster than `Do`